# What memory to buy for macbook pro 17" early 2011?

Tags: macbook-pro, memory

What brand/model of memory do I need to buy for a macbook pro 17" early 2011 model?  On [Apple's memory page](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1270#link6), they just say DDR3 1333mhz SODIMM.  So I went to purchase some from Newegg and happened to notice in the comments people complaining the mushkin RAM was not working on their macbook pro...

I just want to find the lowest priced working 8gbytes RAM.

Also, I assume Apple put 2x2gbytes in and I need to purchase 2x4gbytes to replace it.  Is it possible they put 1x4gbytes and so I only need to buy 1x4gbytes to add to it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as the technical specifications (DDR speed, clock, physical size) line up to what Apple lists for your model MBP, you should be fine.

To answer your second question, that isn't possible. MBPs (along with every laptop I have ever opened up) contain only two RAM slots.

Comment: Do you know what tech specs are for the RAM or where I can look that up?  My 2nd question wasn't how many RAM slots there are, I know there are 2, it's whether the included 4gbytes was 2x2gbytes or 1x4gbytes.

Comment: the included ones are always two ram sticks in two slots. Using only one slot would not be beneficial for speed reasons.

Comment: I'd suggest using the [Mac System Scanner app](http://www.crucial.com/systemscanner/MacOS.aspx) from crucial.com -- it will tell you exactly what type of memory is installed in your Mac, and what you should buy if you want to upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

I`d suggest go to http://www.transintl.com/ memory page you will find all information about mac memory.
2nd option use Scanner app

Comment: Please provide more information on the scanner app you've mentioned, with links to it and a brief description.